# genrating url structure inside input field

Tags: jquery

Here i am trying to generate url structure inside input field using some buttons and jquery..i am stuck where one parameter is inserted and after than how can i insert '&' and then next parameter...

here is my current status in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yashm7005/60mwbfe3/4/

```
<button type="button" id="button1" >{bannerid}</button>
      <button type="button" id="button2" >{campaignid}</button>
      <button type="button" id="button3" >{zoneid}</button>
      <input id="input" value="https://www.google.com/" style="width: 50%;"/>
   
      <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button1').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("down");
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    var act = $(this).hasClass("active");
    var value = '?banner={bannerid}';
    if(act){
             $(' #input ').val( function( index, val ) {
          return val + "?banner={bannerid}";
      }); 
      $('#input1').setCursorToTextEnd();
    }else{
              $(' #input ').val(function(index, value) {
           return value.replace('?banner={bannerid}', '');
      });

      }
    });
}); 

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button2').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("down");
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    var act = $(this).hasClass("active");
    var value = '?campaignid={campaignid}';
    if(act){
             $(' #input ').val( function( index, val ) {
          return val + "?campaignid={campaignid}";
      }); 
      $('#input2').setCursorToTextEnd();
    }else{
              $(' #input ').val(function(index, value) {
           return value.replace('?campaignid={campaignid}', '');
      });

      }
    });
}); 

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button3').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("down");
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    var act = $(this).hasClass("active");
    var value = '?zoneid={zoneid}';
    if(act){
             $(' #input ').val( function( index, val ) {
          return val + "?zoneid={zoneid}";
      }); 
      $('#input3').setCursorToTextEnd();
    }else{
              $(' #input ').val(function(index, value) {
           return value.replace('?zoneid={zoneid}', '');
      });

      }
    });
});
```

Comment: Try something like this https://jsfiddle.net/oa20ytkg/

Comment: thank you  its more efficient than mine :)

Comment: I've updated the code in the answer even more

Comment: one more thing.., to  disable buttons when input field is empty..?

Comment: I've updated the demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General there is nothing wrong with your code, but I've improved it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button[id^=button]').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("down");
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    var act = $(this).hasClass("active");
    var s = "";
    $('button[id^=button].active').each(function() {
      var target = $(this).attr("data-target") + '=' + $(this).text();
      s += (s == "" ? "?" : "&") + target
    })
    $('#input').val(function() {
      var t = $(this).val().split('?')[0];
      return t + s
    })

  });
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button[id^=button]').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("down");
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    var act = $(this).hasClass("active");
    var s = "";
    $('button[id^=button].active').each(function() {
      var target = $(this).attr("data-target") + '=' + $(this).text();
      s += (s == "" ? "?" : "&") + target
    })
    $('#input').val(function() {
      var t = $(this).val().split('?')[0];
      return t + s
    })
  });
    $('#input').on('keyup', function() {
      $('button[id^=button]').prop("disabled", $(this).val().length == 0);
    })
});
```

```css
button#button1 {
  margin: 4px 4px 0 0;
  padding: 0 8px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 12px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  appearance: none;
  transition: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

button#button1.down {
  background-color: rgb(0, 128, 255);
  color: #ffffff;
}

button#button2 {
  margin: 4px 4px 0 0;
  padding: 0 8px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 12px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  appearance: none;
  transition: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

button#button2.down {
  background-color: rgb(0, 128, 255);
  color: #ffffff;
}

button#button3 {
  margin: 4px 4px 0 0;
  padding: 0 8px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 12px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  appearance: none;
  transition: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

button#button3.down {
  background-color: rgb(0, 128, 255);
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button type="button" id="button1" data-target="banner">{bannerid}</button>
  <button type="button" id="button2" data-target="campaign">{campaignid}</button>
  <button type="button" id="button3" data-target="zone">{zoneid}</button>
  <input id="input" value="https://www.google.com/" style="width: 50%;" />




</body>

</html>
```